# Can't Create Virtual Environments after Upgrade to Mavericks

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-mavericks, virtualenvwrapper

I recently upgraded to 10.9 Mavericks.  I updated brew, and installed python 2.7.6 for my dev environment.  I also changed my /etc/paths so that /usr/local/bin/ comes before /usr/bin.  Everything seemed to be working fine, except that when I try to create a virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper, I get a traceback error saying DistributionNotFound: virtualenv.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.5
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Cleaning up...
$ mkvirtualenv test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.11.5
```

The following is in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: have you tried downgrading virtualenv or trying the latest release?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Thanks for the suggestion.  Downgrading to a previous version of virtualenvwrapper did the trick.

Comment: no worries, I thought it might.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by running:

```
    sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
    sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1
```